# Converting 3D points to 2D points?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, 3d

Given:

```
p1 = (-10,  2, -0.01)
p2 = (-20, -2, -0.03)
```

I am trying to represent these points in a 3D rectangle, where I have width, height and depth of the 3D rectangle. Here, the projection type is orthographic and it is Cartesian co-ordinate system

By converting p1 and p2 to 2D, I would like to draw line.

Any idea how could it be done?

Here is the image

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222025/curvilinear-perspective-convert-3d-to-2d

Comment: Why can't you just take the X and Y but not the Z. so p1 would be (-10,2) p2 would be (-20,-2)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for but not sure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: @shaunhusain, it is complicated explanation to understand from that link. any direct formula would be help full

Comment: If I converted the JS provided by pimvdb into AS3 would that be considered a solution to your problem? I can port it pretty easily I think.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called an [orthographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection).  It is a bit simpler to understand than the more general [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), although you may want to look into that, as well.

An intuitive way to understand orthographic projection:  each axis in your 3d coordinate system (e.g., the H-, W-, and D- axes in your example) has a 2d *direction vector* in your screen coordinates (i.e., the `(x,y)` coordinates you use for drawing):

```
let:  H-axis direction vector = (hx, hy)
      W-axis direction vector = (wx, wy)
      D-axis direction vector = (dx, dy)

and:  origin screen position = (ox, oy)
```

To understand what these direction vectors mean:  if you draw the H-axis, and mark it up with tics for `(H=0, H=1, H=2, ...)`, then  `hx` is the difference in x-coordinates between successive tics, and `hy` is the difference in y-coordinates between successive tics.  So, you can change the direction and scale of any axis (independent of the others!) by playing with its direction vector.

Once you have chosen your origin point and direction vectors, you can compute screen coordinates `(x, y)` as:

```
      x = H * hx + W * wx + D * dx + ox
      y = H * hy + W * wy + D * dy + oy
```

The highly regular multiply/add structure of this formula is basically [matrix multiplication](http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication):

```
[ x y ]  =  [ H W D 1 ] * [ hx hy ]
                          [ wx wy ]
                          [ dx dy ]
                          [ ox oy ]
```

Comment: i think we are very close, when u say, H-axis vector = (hx, hy), hx=min value hy=max value of axis?  right. can we chat for few minute in chat room

Comment: No, `(hx, hy)` is the direction the H-axis points.  If you draw the H-axis, and mark it up with ticks for `(H=0, H=1, H=2 ...)`, then `hx` is the difference in the x-coordinates of successive ticks, and `hy` is the difference in the y-coordinates of successive ticks.  So, you can change the direction and scale of any axis (independently of the others!) by playing around with its direction vector.

Comment: am not getting it, hx and hy, how do u find out for axis. I have uploaded image by editing Q, which show ticks marks. from that image could u pls help me to find the values  :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to add my above explanation.  I have also created a chat room for further discussion, called "orthographic projection"

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following points because they're easier to work with:

```
p1 = (50, 100, 0)
p2 = (200, 250, 50)
```

To create a 3D rectangle (a cube), you'd need to go through a few steps:

- Convert the two points into the corner points of a cube. For example, the front lower right hand corner has its front and bottom coordinates of `p1` and its horizontal coordinate of `p2`.
- Use the projection formulas for orthographic projection. In its simplest form, you could use this:

```
2D       3D
x   =   x + z
y   =   y - z
```

- Make up the lines that the cube consists of, such as the bottom front horizontal line, etc.

I don't know ActionScript but here's a proof of concept that should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/3NLVe/.

Comment: Thanks, it did not worked for me. am trying add those two points inside 3D Cartesian rectangle!

Comment: Add them in a rectangle? Sorry, but that doesn't really make things clear. Do you have a clear (visual) idea of what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Q is edited, I have added image of the rectangle. pls. have look at it